# Restore deleted Folder with testdisk recursively

Tags: testdisk

I want recover a large deleted directory.
While I found it with testdisk, I don't know how to recover full folders but only files.

How can I **restore all deleted files in a *folder* recursively**?

Comment: If you're down to file scavenging then your folder hierarchy is long gone, sorry.

Comment: I don't think I am. I just used testdisk because I knew it. Is there a better tool for this?
The hierachy still seems to be intact